# Which event handler gets fired after server closes the connection?

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm using [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) to manage web sockets. In an instance, I implement four event handlers, onOpen, onMessage, onError and onClose. 
What I need to know is when the web socket connection gets closed by server and which event handlers gets fired. 
Since I'm not the owner of the streaming server I cannot brute close the connection and test in live. 
But if for some reason the server does close the connection, will the onError fire? onClose? Neither?

Comment: https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp#websocketonclose-event => This says the onClose event is fired ... if  I am not completely mistaken.

Comment: It's always better to test such things yourself. Just run your own websocket server in the same console application and see how it goes.